# Cannot PuTTY to centos with ssh

Tags: centos, ssh

New clean server CentOS 5.5 x64

I installed SSHD following the instructions here. 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-ssh/

When I try to login to the server with PuTTY however I get the output below.

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
                   [cursor here]
```

Cursor stuck out to the side. If I hit enter the remote closes the connection?

Am expecting to get

```
Login as:[cursor]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please configure your PuTTY session to use **Port 22** for SSH connections.

(it sounds like you have Port 23 set at the moment)

[image]